# Group by duplicates by one column, but showing another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the data in this table:

```
id  | name
--------------------
265 | crazy row
265 | "crazy row" LTD
273 | simple 
273 | simple & co
273 | "microsoft" corporation
273 | microsoft
284 | oracle
284 | some another
```

I want to remove rows with the same *ID*s, but still display the *name* column.

So the result should look like this:

```
id  | name
--------------------
265 | crazy row
273 | simple 
284 | oracle
```

It doesn't matter which name value will be displayed: first [crazy row] or last ["crazy row" LTD].

I've written something, but of course it's wrong

```
 SELECT 
    l.[id], [name]
 FROM 
    [list] l
 JOIN 
    (SELECT [id]
     FROM [list]
     GROUP BY [id]
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x ON l.id = x.id
```

Edited: there are normal rows (not duplicates) in my table. My aim is to find duplicates and show single name, that's because in my sql code I'm finding duplicates first

Comment: You need to put it in an aggregated value, so you could try MAX([name]) for instance, or any other function that returns one of the many values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here u are

```
select ID, max(name ) from [list] l
group by id
```

Comment: we usually need more than 2 eyes